# Rails not loading bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails and working through a (not very good) tutorial, but I'm getting stuck on a part with the Rails pipeline.

I added `gem bootstrap-sass` to my Gemfile and then ran (from my Rails application's root directory) `bin/bundle install`.

```
$ bin/bundle show bootstrap-sass
```

responds with the following, so I'm assuming that bootstrap-sass is installed

```
$ /Users/cosette/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.2.0.2
```

I modified my `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` so it looks like:

```
 /*
  * [boilerplate text generated by rails] 
  *
  *= require_tree .
  *= require bootstrap
  *= require_self
  */
```

Now if I start up `bin/rails server`:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-04-05 15:30:08] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-04-05 15:30:08] INFO  ruby 2.1.2 (2014-05-08) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
[2015-04-05 15:30:08] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3904 port=3000
```

and point my web browser to `http://localhost:3000/posts`, I get `Sprockets::FileNotFound in Posts#index`. This is the output in the Rails console:

```
Started GET "/posts" for ::1 at 2015-04-05 15:31:03 -0400
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
  Post Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered collection (38.1ms)
  Rendered posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (65.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 124ms (ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'bootstrap'
  (in /Users/cosette/Documents/workspace/rails/code/social/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:14)):
    2: <html>
    3: <head>
    4:   <title>Social</title>
    5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    6:   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    8: </head>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2483101853858498351_70166979821380'
```

Does anybody know how to get this to work? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the bootstrap-saas gem [documentation](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#a-ruby-on-rails) you need to:

- rename `application.css` file to `application.scss`
- import boostrap files like :

  `@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
  @import "bootstrap";`

Hope this helps

Comment: Also remove all `*= require xyz` directives.